# How to add field into existing salesforce data extension?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions

I have a salesforce (report) data extension, data imported and automated, now I need to add another field. I added said field in salesforce report. How can I add that field to existing data extension ? I tried adding new field into data extension but when I run import activity no data imported into this field.

Kind Regards,

Comment: if the below answered your question, please consider accepting it. Same goes for all your other posts, you have not accepted any answer in any of them. Help the community by marking them accepted is they helped resolve your question so it will prove useful to others. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You have to re-create your [Import Activity](https://help.marketingcloud.com/en/documentation/exacttarget/interactions/activities/import_activity/) in SFMC.

Comment: Oh dear ! we have round 250 filtered data extension on that and API keys being used in other application. That mean recreating import activity we have to recreate all filtered data extensions again and API ids will be changed as well. :(